# Method of characteristics for the Beltrami equation when $\mu$ is real analytic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, teichmueller-theory

I am reading a proof of the measurable mapping theorem which shows the existence of a solution to the [Beltrami equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_equation#CITEREFAstalaIwaniecMartin2009) in the simple case when $\mu \in  L^{\infty}(\mathbb{C})$ is real analytic (due to Gauss)

\begin{equation}
(1-\mu(x,y))\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}+ i(1+\mu(x,y)))\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=0
\tag{4.5.8}
\end{equation}

From what I understand, we are looking for a curve $(x(t), y(t))$ which satisfies

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=1-\mu(x,y)$$ and
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=i(1+\mu(x,y))$$.

The author then points out that such a curve would satisfy 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= i\frac{1+u}{1-u} \tag{*}$$

**I wanted to understand how one goes from the system of ODE's above to (*). Does $\mu$ being real analytic imply that there is a solution to the system above**

Furthermore, if there is such a solution, the inverse function theorem tells us that the solution is a local homeomorphism, can we say anything about uniqueness just from the ODE theory?

Comment: I suspect your third equation should read $dy/dt = i(1 + \mu(x, y))$, not $dx/dt = i(1 + \mu(x, y))$.  Could I be right?  Cheers!

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help out, my friend!

Comment: Are you asking how $$x' = 1 - \mu, \quad y' = i(1+\mu) \implies \frac{y'}{x'} = \frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{i(1+\mu)}{1-\mu}$$?

Comment: Yes, I realized the chain rule here, after posting the question. So I think I understand that such a $y$ exists because $i(1+\mu)/(1-\mu)$ is something that can be integrated.